# How to get the data using >= AND <= in a 12hr time format in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I want to get the time from 12:00:00 PM to 02:00:00 PM but it doesn't work when I use `start_time >= '12:00:00' AND end_time <= '02:00:00'`. I have this code so far.
 Note: I'm using Code Igniter.

```
    $start =  date("g:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('start')));
    $end =  date("g:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('end')));
    $date_reserve =  $this->input->post('date_reserve');

    $sql = "SELECT materialID FROM schedule WHERE date_reserve = ? AND start_time >= ? AND end_time <= ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($date_reserve,$start,$end));
```

I use `g:i:s` to format it in a 12hr time format. And when I try to echo it, gives me `12:00:00` and `02:00:00` it doesn't get the `AM/PM`. And also the data type of start_time and end_time in my DB is `time`. What is the proper way to retrieve the data and what data type should I use in my DB. Thanks!.

Comment: RTM [**DATE_FORMAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) ?

Comment: @Hamza: You forgot the `F` in `RTM` though :D

Comment: @TobiasKun [I know :D](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181040/we-need-to-be-a-little-less-hostile)

Comment: @Leonard: Why not use `h:i:s` (24h a day) format? This would help you a lot ;)

Comment: @TobiasKun: What's the differences between `g:i:s` and `h:i:s`

Comment: `h:i:s` will return for example `14:00:00` instead of `02:00:00`. And this is the same way it is treated in sql.

Comment: So it is something like `24hr format`?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza: Yes i said it in my previous comment.

Comment: Always *always* **always** use 24hr times for the DB. If you need 12hr times on the user interface, convert them when you display them, but keep them as 24hr times on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use the `DATETIME`-format as datatype in your database this should help you:

```
$start =  date("h:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('start')));
$end =  date("h:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('end')));
...
$sql = "SELECT materialID FROM schedule WHERE date_reserve = ? AND TIME(start_time) >= ? AND TIME(end_time) <= ?";
```

**Edit:** 
So if you use `TIME-format` you only have to change the format of the values you are inserting:

```
$start =  date("h:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('start')));
$end =  date("h:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('end')));
```

Comment: Honestly I don't use a `datetime`. I have a timepicker and you can only choose `time`, the date is disabled.

Comment: It cannot retrieve the data from `12:00:00 PM` to `02:00:00 PM`

Comment: My timepicker is base from http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ and I have this configuration: http://codejaw.com/nzg3vsg

Comment: And you pass both values after form submit to your query in this format `h:i:s / 14:00:00`? Can you show me an example row from your database with start - and end-time?

Comment: yes it is in `h:i:s:` format but i'm worried the time is not converted to `14:00:00` but I do use `h:i:s:`

Comment: Did you ever debugged the query?

Comment: Yes I did just like what you've answered

Comment: KunL: Hey I got it already but if I try to query `13:30:00` to `14:00:00` I get nothing. How can I get the data in my DB from 1:30PM to 2PM? I have start_time = `13:00:00` to `14:00:00` in my DB